# micro ros arduino Deserialization of data failed -> function deserialize_change error

Tags: ros2, arduino, micro-ros

Setup:

- Arduino Portenta H7 & Arduino Nano RP2040 Connect
- Host PC running ROS2 Foxy and micro ros agent

Problem:
I get this error from time to time and randomly

**`Subscriber error : Deserialization of data failed -> function deserialize_change`**

[image: ERROR]

when I try to read the data published by the board (either one) one ros2 topics.
I get the data that I want, ultrasonic sensor readings, but sometimes I get this error. It seems that the data published has some corrupt info, eventhough I have filtered out in my code any other characters that are not ASCII characters.

Any fix for this ?

Code:

```
#include <micro_ros_arduino.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <rcl/rcl.h>
#include <rcl/error_handling.h>
#include <rclc/rclc.h>
#include <rclc/executor.h>

#include <std_msgs/msg/string.h>
#include <cctype>

rcl_publisher_t publisher;
std_msgs__msg__String msg;
rclc_executor_t executor;
rclc_support_t support;
rcl_allocator_t allocator;
rcl_node_t node;
rcl_timer_t timer;

int triggerPins[] = {2, 4, 6};  
int echoPins[] = {3, 5, 7};     

unsigned long durations[3];

#define LED_PIN 13

#define RCCHECK(fn) { rcl_ret_t temp_rc = fn; if((temp_rc != RCL_RET_OK)){error_loop();}}
#define RCSOFTCHECK(fn) { rcl_ret_t temp_rc = fn; if((temp_rc != RCL_RET_OK)){}}   

void error_loop(){
  while(1){
    digitalWrite(LED_PIN, !digitalRead(LED_PIN));
    delay(100);
  }
}

void timer_callback(rcl_timer_t * timer, int64_t last_call_time)
{  
  RCLC_UNUSED(last_call_time);
  if (timer != NULL) {
    RCSOFTCHECK(rcl_publish(&publisher, &msg, NULL));
  }
}

bool isASCII(char c) {return (c >= 32 && c <= 126);}
bool isAlNum(char c) {return (c >= '0' && c <= '9') || (c>= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= 'a' && c<= 'z');}

void removeSpecialCharacters(char* str) {
  for (int i =0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i){
    if (!isASCII(str[i]) && isAlNum(str[i])){
      // If the character is not alphanumeric or a space, remove it
      for (int j = i; str[j] != '\0'; ++j){
        str[j] = str[j + 1];
      }
      --i; 
    }
  }
}

void setup() {
  set_microros_wifi_transports("SSID", "PASS", "192.168.X.XX", 8888);

  pinMode(LED_PIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(LED_PIN, HIGH);  
  
  delay(2000);

  allocator = rcl_get_default_allocator();

  //create init_options
  RCCHECK(rclc_support_init(&support, 0, NULL, &allocator));

  // create node
  RCCHECK(rclc_node_init_default(&node, "micro_ros_arduino_node", "", &support));

  // create publisher
  RCCHECK(rclc_publisher_init_default(
    &publisher,
    &node,
    ROSIDL_GET_MSG_TYPE_SUPPORT(std_msgs, msg, String),
    "micro_ros_arduino_node_publisher"));

  // create timer,
  const unsigned int timer_timeout = 700;
  RCCHECK(rclc_timer_init_default(
    &timer,
    &support,
    RCL_MS_TO_NS(timer_timeout),
    timer_callback));

  // create executor
  RCCHECK(rclc_executor_init(&executor, &support.context, 1, &allocator));
  RCCHECK(rclc_executor_add_timer(&executor, &timer));
  
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    pinMode(triggerPins[i], OUTPUT);
    pinMode(echoPins[i], INPUT_PULLDOWN);
  }
  
  msg.data.data = " ";
}

void loop() {
  delay(100);
  RCSOFTCHECK(rclc_executor_spin_some(&executor, RCL_MS_TO_NS(100)));
  char terminal[100] = " ";
  
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    
    digitalWrite(triggerPins[i], LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(10); 
    digitalWrite(triggerPins[i], HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(10); 
    digitalWrite(triggerPins[i], LOW);
    durations[i] = pulseIn(echoPins[i], HIGH, 40000UL);

    double distanceCm = (double)durations[i] / 2.0 * 0.0343;

    char durationString[10] = " ";

    char direction[10] = " ";
    if (i==0){strcat(direction, "Front");}
    else if (i==1){strcat(direction, "Angle");}
    else {strcat(direction, "Side");}
    
    char sensorData[50]; // Is up above
    sprintf(sensorData, "Distance %s is %s cm\n", direction, durationString);

    strcat(terminal, sensorData);
  }
  removeSpecialCharacters(terminal);
  msg.data.data = terminal;
}
```